# Xamarin Forms-(IOS) System.Net.WebException has been thrown

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Am new in **Xamarin Forms** and am trying to retrieve `JSON`data plus images from web  into a `ListView`  but , i read about **ATS** https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/ and i tried to implement it in `info.plist` below is the screenshot but still i get `System.Net.WebException`.

**My Image**

[Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qag9.png)

**This is the Error i get :**

```
   $exception   {System.Net.WebException: 
    The resource could not be loaded because 
the App Transport Security policy …}    
System.Net.WebException
```

**This is my  Class page**  `OnlineStreaming.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class OnlineStreaming : ContentPage
    {
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        public ObservableCollection<Adverts> adverts;
        private const string Url = "http://eamobiledirectory.com/cooperp/Mobile/Mobileapi.aspx?Action=Featured&Country=Uganda";
        private const string BaseImageUrl = "http://eamobiledirectory.com/cooperp/Images/app_images/";

        public OnlineStreaming()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {

            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var adv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Adverts>>(content);

            adverts = new ObservableCollection<Adverts>(adv);

            foreach (var item in adverts)
            {
                //some coding



                adverts.Add(new Adverts
                {

                    company_name = item.company_name
                                       ,
                    office_photo = BaseImageUrl + item.office_photo
                });

                //Debug.WriteLine("Output  is here  :" +  item.company_name);


            }



            listViewTest.ItemsSource = adverts;




        }
    }
```

**my Xaml Page :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="Online Streaming"
    x:Class="BBSTV.OnlineStreaming">



    <ListView  x:Name="listViewTest">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                    <Image  Aspect="Fill"  Source="{Binding office_photo}"/>
                        <Label  TextColor="Gray" Text="{Binding company_name}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Please help me guys why is this on IOS.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your app needs to load and display web content from non-secure
>   sites, add the following to your app's Info.plist file to allow web
>   pages to load correctly while Apple Transport Security (ATS)
>   protection is still enabled for the rest of the app:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

you need to set NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent to true . **Current you have set false.**

clean project and run again

Comment: i added **NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent**  plus  **NSAllowsArbitraryLoads** , and i set all to true but still it's bringing the same exception, please help me where am i wrong.

Comment: remove all related keys to ATS and use suggested  answer.

Comment: yes @KKRocks , i removed all of them and i used your solution  but still the same error , am confused :(

Comment: I used the same bundle name in Xcode and Xamarin , does it mean that also in Xcode i edit the `info.plist file` ? or

Comment: how can i delete an App in a simulator

Comment: long click on app icon then you will see cross button then press on it and delete it

Comment: man i dont know now whats the root cause of the problem , still no change :(

Comment: @IdrisStack are you there ? i

Comment: Yes am here @KKRocks

Comment: can you check that how many plist file exist in your project and in which plist  you made above changes ?

Comment: can you tell me in comment . how many plist file exist in your project ?

Comment: They are **15** , but also i have updated the post check the image link.

Comment: and you need to make change in that plist which contained by project folder.  and see my update answer.

Comment: Ok , atleast now the Exception  has changed its saying   `System.InvalidOperationException` and  **Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**

Comment: But it seems to have worked , now how can i remove this new error , do i have to modify the observable collection ?

Comment: :-) . am happy now